# Two different condition for two different colums using case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table of random numbers as follows:
** Person table schema **

- Name
- Marks1
- Marks2

I want to return a table with similar structure and headings, where if the sum of a column is odd, the column shows the maximum value for that column, and when the sum is even, it shows the minimum value by using a case statement.

** output table schema **

- Marks1
- Marks2

I've tried the following code.

```
select Marks1,Marks2 ,
  (case
      when mod(sum(Marks1),2)=0 then
          min(Marks1)
      else max(Marks1)
  end) as Marks1 , 
  (case 
   when mod(sum(Marks2),2)=0 then
          min(Marks2)
      else max(Marks2)
  end) as Marks2
from numbers
group by Marks1;
```

Sample output -
TABLE

Ash    56       45

David  45       35

Output -

56    35

As 56+45 = 101 odd number so output 56(max number). Whereas in marks2 column, 45+35 =80, even number so output 35(min number).

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is not that clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please add some sample data and desired output

Comment: added the sample output

Comment: I think you want to group by name instead and remove marks1 and marks2 from the select, keeping only the case statements

Comment: there is no 'name' column in the output table. ignore the group by command if you want.

Comment: @Shinichi Then remove the group by and also marks1, and marks2 from the select

Comment: Your problem statement and results do not match.  In your problem statement you want `min()` in the case of odd, but in your sample results, you use `max()` in the case of odd.

Comment: I am with Mithrandir here: If you want one result row, then remove the `GROUP BY`, as a `GROUP BY` clause leads to multiple result rows (one per group). Then remove Marks1 and Marks2 from the `SELECT` clause, because in that one result line the two make no sense (there are various Marks1 and Marks2 in the table, not just one each).

Comment: When posting a query, you should also tell us what happens when you run it (the syntax error message in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE to get your `min()`, `max()`, and `sum()` values.  Then use `case` to determine what values to display.

Since your problem statement and sample results do not match, I followed your sample results to return `max()` on an odd `sum()`.  You can switch this by changing the two `case` statements from `1` to `0`.

[Working fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0173a/5)

```
with totals as (
  select sum(marks1) as marks1sum,
         min(marks1) as marks1min,
         max(marks1) as marks1max,
         sum(marks2) as marks2sum,
         min(marks2) as marks2min,
         max(marks2) as marks2max
    from numbers
)
select case mod(marks1sum, 2)
         when 1 then marks1max
         else marks1min
       end as marks1,
       case mod(marks2sum, 2)
         when 1 then marks2max
         else marks2min
       end as marks2
  from totals;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing marks1 and marks2  when  aliasing your  third and fourth column which is colliding. Try using different name.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Please read it carefully.